# Mem leak in pyqt test with pytest

Tags: memory-leaks, pyqt, pytest, pyqt5

Does anyone have an explanation for why the following leaks memory (the memory and other kernel objects like GDI and User handles keep increasing at every iteration and never go back down until test exits):

```
import pytest
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView

class TestCase:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('dummy', range(1000))
    def test_empty(self, dummy):
        # self.view = None   # does NOT fix the leak if uncommented!
        self.app = QApplication.instance()
        if self.app is None:
            self.app = QApplication([])
        self.view = QGraphicsView()
        self.view.setFixedSize(600, 400)
        self.view.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        self.view.show()

        QTimer.singleShot(100, self.app.exit)
        self.app.exec()

        # self.view = None   # FIXES the leak if uncommented!
```

There is no leak if any of the following conditions becomes True:

1. If I None-ify view *before* test method returns (uncomment the last line)
2. If I make the view local to the
   function instead of a member of self (not surprising given fix #1)
3. If I remove the decorator and
   instead have a "while True" at the top of the function (so the test
   itself runs once but the window gets recreated over and over)

Interestingly, the leak does NOT go away if I make any of the following modifications:

1. I set the view to None at the beginning of the function instead of at the end (commented out line at beginning of test method)
2. Instead of parameterizing the test method, I create many test methods (100's, easily done with a little python script that generates the test module), or many test classes, many test modules (that's how I noticed the problem, we have a huge test suite consisting of 100 test modules with several classes in each, each having many test methods -- the memory leak in the test suite went unnoticed until recently when the number of tests became large enough that the OS is now running out of GDI handles before pytest finishes running all tests!).
3. I replace the single-shot call to app.exit() by app.closeAllWindows() (I thought this might have been the issue in this MCVE)

The actual tests in our app require that some objects be created in the setup_method(), hence we cannot avoid assigning PyQt objects to data members of the test instance. So the only practical solution for us now is to edit each test method to None-ify PyQt objects created by the methods but this will be error prone, not to mention laborious (although better than current situation). I'm hoping there is a better way.

Comment: The view doesn't take ownership of the scene, so you should keep a reference to it.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, the actual code does this. In fact, you can remove the line with setScene() and you will still have the leak.

Comment: See also https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1649

Comment: @dbw holy... this is not good. So this is not even specific to PyQt... is there a way to define a tear down function called automatically for every method of every test class of every test module? Otherwise I have to add a line of code to every setup_method() to grab the current test's dict, and a line in every teardown_method() to grab the new dict and None-ify every attribute that was not in the setup_method grab. Note also that sometimes the order of destruction matters (I would guess, only when there is C/C++ extension module involved): some objects need to be garbaged last.

Comment: The proper solution to this, IMHO, is to use pytest's fixture system instead.

Comment: Yeah, if you are not using a unittest TestCase (w setUp and tearDown), there should not be a reason to set attributes on a Test instance. You may also want to look into the pytest-qt package to help you clean up.

Comment: @dbw We use setup_method teardown_method etc. There is too much code to move away from assigning to self attributes in the setup_method() but I created a fixture that does the cleanup after each test, works well. I will post as answer in case useful to others.

Comment: Good plan, @Schollii.

Comment: @dbw done, feedback welcome

Answer (score 3):

The solution we used might benefit others so I post it as an answer (although I just saw in the 3.0.4 release of pytest that the problem might have gotten fixed). First a bit of background:

- we have a lot of tests (almost a 1000) that were created at a time when we were still using nosetests as the test driver
- we eventually migrated the test suite to pytest using nose2pytest plugin (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose2pytest)
- we have a lot of setup/teardown methods on test classes to create the same objecst for all test methods of a test class. The objects are available to the test class instance methods by creating an attribute on self:

  ```
  class TestCase: 
      def setup_method(self):
          self.a = 123
      def test_something(self):
          ...use self.a...
  ```

The problem is that at the end of each test method, pytest harvests any attribute of self that was created during the test method, stores it in some cache, and removes it from TestCase instance (at least for pytest < 3.0.4). The problem with this of course is that as the test suite grows, certain critical resources do not get released: memory, GDI handles, USER handles, etc.

Eventually, our test suite got large enough that it would crash unexplainably but always after running for a while. At first we thought it was something we were doing wrong in our PyQt code, but found that moving some tests to a separate test suite (run as a separate pytest command) did not cause any crash so we lived with for a while until even that wasn't enough and we noticed the members leak. This is not surprising given the pytest behavior described above (which we did not know at the time). In one of our suites, the memory would go up to 1.2 gigs, and the GDI handles to 10000, at which point the test suite would crash. Indeed, a search on web indicates that default [max GDI handles per Windows process is 10k](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx), confirmed by looking at the Windows registry.

Enough background, now how we tackled this.

So we just finished implementing the following transformation and it makes a huge difference: we created a fixture that automatically removes any attributes added by a test method before pytest gets a chance to harvest them. This was achieved in a few steps:

1. we renamed every `setup_method(self)` to `setup_teardown_each(self, request, cleanup_attribs)` and decorated it with `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)`. This was easy to do with regular expression search-replace.
2. we replaced the `def teardown_method(self)` lines by a `yield` which, thanks to our consistent layout of test where for every test class the `def teardown` was right after the `def setup_method`, means this was another easy step. Otherwise we would have had to add a yield in the setup fixture, move the body code of teardown to after yield, and remove the teardown method.
3. we defined the `cleanup_attribs` fixture in the suite's `conftest.py`:

   ```
   @pytest.fixture
   def cleanup_attribs(request):
       test_case = request.node.instance
       attr_names = set(test_case.__dict__.keys())
       yield

       # upon teardown:
       attr_names_added = set(test_case.__dict__.keys()).difference(attr_names)
       if not attr_names_added:
           return

       log.info('cleanup_attribs fixture removing {} from {}', attr_names_added, request.node.nodeid)
       test_case = request.node.instance
       for attr_name in attr_names_added:
           delattr(test_case, attr_name)
   ```

This works because this fixture is a dependency of the setup_teardown_each fixture, so the portion before yield is run before the setup, and the portion after yield is run after test method runs and, if setup also yielded, after setup completely finishes. The fixture first gets current dict of test case, and after yield it finds what was added and removes them.

After this was put in place, the test suite uses at most a couple hundred GDI handles and a couple hundred megs mem, a huge difference. This allowed us to merge two test suites since they no longer run out of memory and GDI handles.